# How to change cursor's place at java

Tags: java

I am doing a project with using arraylist. I want a alphabet and a number in order from user .

```
char karakter = klavye.next().charAt(0);   
    int sayi = klavye.nextInt();
```

When i write that after first input cursor pass to the bottom line
like:
A
7
But i want like that A 7 Why do not they side by side? How can i do this?

Comment: Not easily, so think carefully whether you want to take on 3rd party libraries and platform dependent customization. See [here](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/) for some information on why this is problematic (and solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you just want the user to be able to enter two tokens on the same line. One approach is to just get the whole line and then split it into tokens.

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
String tokens[] = klavye.nextLine().split(" ");
while(tokens.length < 2) { 
    System.out.println("Bad line, enter again:");
    tokens = klavye.nextLine().split(" ");
}
char karakter = tokens[0].charAt(0);
System.out.println("karakter = " + karakter);
int sayi = Integer.valueOf(tokens[1]);
System.out.println("sayi = " + sayi);
```

The user should type `A 7` then press the enter key only once at the end.

Comment: That will happen if someone enters a line that does not have a space in the middle as required.  Added check for this.